# if I have 6 sections with 2 displayed on the screen, and I scroll down.. Do I effectively have 2 sections (reusability) or  6 sections?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, reusability

This may be a very basic question. But I am finding it confusing with my tableView acting weird when I scroll up and down.

So UITableViewCells are **Reusable** !! So each row in my tableViewCell is reusable, and so, if I scroll down, I tend to use the same cells for different purposes (as programmed). My assumption is that 'a cell is a row'

Are `sections` reusable as well ?

So if I have *6 sections* with *2 displayed on the screen* at the moment, and I scroll down.... Do I effectively have 2 sections being reused thrice or do I have 6 sections ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *Section* is just visual appearance of groups of *UITableViewCells* in a *UITableView*. It is not a object or something that one can reuse.

Another reason why sections can not be made reusable is that, its rare that two sections contain same number of rows of same kinds of cells.

The only reusable elements in a table view are *UITableViewCells*.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it a section is not an object where a cell is. Therefore you do not need to give a section any memory as you do when you allocate a cell so do not need to recycle the sections in order to save memory. They are just indices for which section you are in. So "no" I think is the answer.

Perhaps if you posted your code we could be more help.

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Cells are rows, yes. Sections themselves aren't reusable, but you can dictate which kind of cell gets reused for each section using the `reuseIdentifier`. That may give you the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: So if I have 6 sections with 2 displayed on the screen at the moment, and I scroll down, I effectively have 2 sections being reused thrice or do I have 6 sections ?

Comment: Don't really think in sections. Sections are just a grouping of rows. In your case you can create a grouping of rows that share a reuseIdentifier. If you have 6 seconds, each with 4 rows, and you have 8 rows on screen. Then the reuse behavior depends on how you use your identifiers. You may want to read the Table View Programming Guide.